# Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT - Strapi 3.0.0 (beta 17.4)

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js, strapi

I have exact 2 copies of database in development and production environment, but in production i can't create an entry, gives an error:

```
error Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT. Undefined column(s): [categories.id] query: select categories.* from categories where categories.id = ? limit ?
```

I am trying to create an entry from admin panel:

"/admin/plugins/content-manager/category/create?redirectUrl=/plugins/content-manager/category?source=content-manager"

Categories table has relation, one category to many news, and reverse, one news can have only one category.

Comment: Hello! can you give more details about where your error came from. Is it a backed error, a frontend error?
What is the Strapi version you use?